# Linq to Entities: see the resulting query (context.Log = Console.Out)

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I just realized if your C# application use LINQ-TO-SQL classes to interface with the database, you can your query like this

```
        using (DatabaseContext context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            context.Log = Console.Out;
            var query = from Person p in context.People
                        where person.Name == "john"
                        select p;                                
            Console.WriteLine(query.Name);
        }
```

What is the equivalent in LINQ-TO-ENTITY (is this another name for ADO.NET?) for
`context.Log = Console.Out`
Or there is another way to see your actual SQL query to the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log Entity Framework SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659249/how-to-log-entity-framework-sql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always use SQL Profiler if you have MS SQL Server. What DBMS is this for? LINQ 2 Entities supports multiple DB types.

This also works...

```
var cust = (from c in context.Customers select c);

string sql = ((ObjectQuery)cust).ToTraceString();
```

From [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/6df9599f-c165-4a0e-9b92-ca58a8fc3816/)

Comment: @sliverNnja this is for sql 2008 R2 express. +1 for mentioning SQL Profiler

Answer (score 2):

Using EntityFrame 6 it is possible to just to a ToString() on your query at least when using MySQL

```
var cust = (from c in context.Customers select c);
string sql = cust.ToString();
```

As Greg in the comments notes, this gives you the parameterized query, so you will need to add in the values you want to use.

Comment: This is useful.  It won't give you the exact sql like Profiler will, but instead it will be parameterized.  But this was helpful in SQL Server when I was having an issue with Profiler.

Comment: Entity Framework actually returns the output as `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`

Answer (score 0):

You can trace your SQL when using Linq2Entities
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137712/sql-tracing-linq-to-entities

You may also want to look at this tool
[Huagati Query Profiler](http://huagati.blogspot.com/2010/06/entity-framework-support-in-huagati.html)

Comment: That "SQL tracing LINQ to Entities" link no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Tabular Data Stream ([TDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx)) protocol used by Microsoft SQL Server sends commands and responses in plain text by default so unless you encrypt the connection between your SQL Server and the client, you *should* be able to view both the request and response with a comprehensive [packet sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_sniffer).

It will take some work but using a packet sniffer in this manner should allow you to see what T-SQL your LINQ is getting translated to.

**Side Notes**:

1. I recommend that you encrypt all communications between your client and SQL server unless both the client and server reside on the same machine and you are doing *development* testing.
2. If you can't risk using a decyrpted connection for testing purposes, your packet sniffer *may* have a plugin that will allow you to decrypt encrypted traffic, but I am not sure if there are any risks in using such a decryption plugin.

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't have a direct parallel to the stream based loging that LINQ to SQL uses. There are a number of profiling options available for a variety of costs. I've discussed some of these options at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-to-Database-Performance-hints. You can find a listing of these profilers and other LINQ tools at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/linq-tools.